# At what stage does Typescript actually do compilation?

Tags: javascript, typescript, compilation

I'm reading that Typescript code is compiled in order to check types etc. Whenever I've written Typescript code, it seems to operate exactly like Javascript except that it checks types as you type code. I know that Javascript is not compiled. So my question is:

Does Typescript do continuous compilation as you type code, where Javascript does not do compilation at all? If not, where/when/how does Typescript code get compiled?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Typescript is not compiled. It is transpiled into Javascript.

Comment: TypeScript is a typed superset of JavaScript that compiles to plain JavaScript. It offers classes, modules, and interfaces to help you build robust components. The TypeScript language specification can be found here.
See here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-compiling

Comment: i think both transpile and compile can be used. even literally tsc stands for 'typescript compiler'

Comment: Yep, thanks. So with respect to my question above, do you know? ^^

Comment: read more here for details: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-compiling

Answer (score 1):

> Does Typescript do continuous compilation as you type code, where Javascript does not do compilation at all?

No, and no.

> If not, where/when/how does Typescript code get compiled?

When you run the `tsc` command in the console (or if you run your buildsystem, e.g. Webpack) it compiles (well, strictly speaking *transpiles*) Typescript into JS.

Comment: Hi @Jonas Wilms, thanks for your reply. I haven't run the tsc command; I'm just using Typescript in React Native. I think React Native runs tsc in its build process. So am I right that when I'm typing along and Typescript highlights stuff in red, that's not part of the transpiling process, whereas the transpiling is when it actually converts it to Javascript?